# How to import JSON object with arrays into ajax autocomplete response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

A company email-generating application I'm working on has an autocomplete input to autofill email theme data into a form. The data is returned as a JSON object, but a couple of the object values `extraps` and `extraul` contain multidimensional arrays. I'm able to get the plain key:value data just fine out in the response, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull the arrays in so I can loop over them to update certain sections of the form.

Here's a look at some of the JSON code coming in:

```
0:
    emaildate: "2019-01-10"
    extraps: Array(2)
        0: {extrap: "test paragraph", position: 1}
        1: {extrap: "another paragraph", position: 3}
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array(0)
    extraul: Array(4)
        0: {ulid: 1, position: 2, li: "list item 1", liposition: 1}
        1: {ulid: 1, position: 2, li: "list item 2", liposition: 2}
        2: {ulid: 1, position: 2, li: "list item something new", liposition: 3}
        3: {ulid: 1, position: 2, li: "A new list item", liposition: 4}
        length: 4
        __proto__: Array(0)
    id: 44
    label: "Some Kind of Email Theme - 2019-01-10"
    lastupdated: "2019-01-06 02:00:04"
    store: "Premier"
    themedesc: "Here's a description of the theme."
    themeimage: null
    themeincludeextrap: 1
    themeincludeul: 1
    themelink: "some-kind-of-email-theme"
    themelinkinclude: 1
    themename: "Some Kind of Email Theme"
    themenotes: "Some notes about it"
    themesortorder: 0
    value: "Some Kind of Email Theme"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And here's a look at the javascript to bring it in from autotheme.php:

```
//Autofill Theme Info based on text entry
$( "#themename" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "autotheme.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        value: item.value,
                        label: item.label,
                        themename: item.themename,
                        themenotes: item.themenotes,
                        themedesc: item.themedesc,
                        themeimage: item.themeimage,
                        themeincludeextrap: item.themeincludeextrap,
                        themeincludeul: item.themeincludeul,
                        themelinkinclude: item.themelinkinclude,
                        themelink: item.themelink,
                        themeextraps: item.extraps,
                        themeextraul: item.extraul
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log("There is an error with theme autocomplete.");
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $this = $(this);
            $('#themeid').val('');
            $('#extratext').html('');
            $('#themename').val(ui.item.themename);
            $('#themenotes').val(ui.item.themenotes);
            $('#themedesc').val(ui.item.themedesc);
            var themeimage = ui.item.themeimage;
            var themeincludeextrap = ui.item.themeincludeextrap;
            var themeincludeul = ui.item.themeincludeul;
            var themelinkinclude = ui.item.themelinkinclude;
            var themeextraps = ui.item.extraps;
            var themeextraul = ui.item.extraul;
            if(themeextraps !== undefined) {
                var extrapcount = themeextraps.length;
            }
            if(themeextraul !== undefined) {
                var extraulcount = themeextraul.length;
            }
            if((themeextraps !== undefined) || (themeextraul !== undefined)) {
                var extratextpositions = {};
                $.each(themeextraps, function(i, themeextraps) {
                    extratextpositions[themeextraps.position] = 'p';
                })
                $.each(themeextraul, function(i, themeextraul) {
                    extratextpositions[themeextraul.position] = 'ul';
                })
                $.each(extratextpositions, function(key, value) {
                    if(extratextpositions[key] == 'p') {
                        addExtraP.call(this);
                    } else {
                        addExtraUl.call(this);
                    }
                });
                $('#themelink').val(ui.item.themelink);
                if(themelinkinclude == 1) {
                    $('#themelinkinclude').prop("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $('#themelinkinclude').prop("checked", false);
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $("#themename").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
        }
    }
});
```

I'm able to get the simple key:value values just fine, but I get undefined for the arrays. I'm sure there's a different way I need to pull those in, but I don't know how and can't seem to find the answer in other threads on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would start by moving the map code out to a `const` and would allow you to test this. Could you post the full function and sample data. Your `map` needs to test for `object`.

Comment: Thanks @Bibberty, I updated to include the full dataset and mostly full function (I took out some stuff that had nothing to do with the question). I'm going to attempt to map out to a const and see where that gets me.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Sorry for not getting the terminology correct. I don't profess to know much about coding, and I know even less about the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to get around this problem, thanks to some help from @Bibberty. I'm not sure if this is the most graceful or easy way to solve it, but it worked for me. I created an array from the JSON data values, then created variables from the arrays within the data array and added them to the response return value. Here's the new functional code (or, at least, the part that matters):

```
//Autofill Theme Info based on text entry
    $( "#themename" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "autotheme.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    const results = data.map(function (value, label) {
                        return [value];
                    })
                    var extraps = results[0][0]['extraps'];
                    var extraul = results[0][0]['extraul'];
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            value: item.value,
                            label: item.label,
                            themename: item.themename,
                            themenotes: item.themenotes,
                            themedesc: item.themedesc,
                            themeimage: item.themeimage,
                            themeincludeextrap: item.themeincludeextrap,
                            themeincludeul: item.themeincludeul,
                            themelinkinclude: item.themelinkinclude,
                            themelink: item.themelink,
                            extraps: extraps,
                            extraul: extraul
                        }
                    }))
                    $("#themename").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log("There is an error with theme autocomplete.");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $this = $(this);
                console.log(ui.item.extraps);
                $('#themeid').val('');
                $('#extratext').html('');
                $('#themename').val(ui.item.themename);
                $('#themenotes').val(ui.item.themenotes);
                $('#themedesc').val(ui.item.themedesc);
                var themeimage = ui.item.themeimage;
                var themeincludeextrap = ui.item.themeincludeextrap;
                var themeincludeul = ui.item.themeincludeul;
                var themelinkinclude = ui.item.themelinkinclude;
                var themeextraps = ui.item.extraps;
                var themeextraul = ui.item.extraul;
                if(themeextraps !== undefined) {
                    var extrapcount = themeextraps.length;
                }
                if(themeextraul !== undefined) {
                    var extraulcount = themeextraul.length;
                }

                ...
```